# How to compile the directory /usr/src/kernel/system in MINIX 3?

Tags: c, unix, minix

I am working in MINIX 3.1.6, and currently I am changing a little thing in **do_fork.C** class which is located int **/usr/src/kernel/system**.

Usually to compile the files in Kernel folder, is use **make install** in the kernel directory, and then **make hdboot**.

I used this form, but it didn't compile me the **../kernel/system** folder! Then I went first in the directory with cd: "**cd /usr/src/kernel/system**" and then I used there **make clean** and **make install**. In the end I used the command **make hdboot** in the directory **/usr/src/tools**

But even that one didn't work... the compiler doesn't show any error or anything, it just doesn't take my changes.

Does anyone know how to compile the whole directory: **/usr/src/kernel/system** in Minix ?

Thanks in Advance

**EDITED**

It's interesting, I did a mistake in `do_fork` class, and when I tried `make install` it showed me an Error. This means that `do_fork.c` is being taken by the `make install`. Can the problem be in the `make hdboot` that it isn't taking the changes of `do_fork.c`?

Comment: is the minux kernel running? if so, is it "allowed" to recompile code while the system is running? (Just guessing. Weird there are no error messages). Good luck.

Comment: Obvious but important question: Are you rebooting the system after running `make hdboot`?

Comment: I think this the only way to compile the MINIX code. Because when you start MINIX you have 2 choices, the Original one, and the Custom Minix (that I am editing). I tried to compile the Code first from the Custom Minix, it didn't take the changes, after reading your comment, I went and compiled the directory from the Original Minix, which doesn't take changes but updates the Custom Minix... it didn't work :(

Comment: @duskwuff, yes I am rebooting the system after `make hdboot`

Comment: I read here: http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs/Lab_Setup/files/WorkingInMinix.pdf , how to compile the Minix code, and for different libraries the guy in this paper, used different ways to compile it. I wonder, is there any other way to compile the code for the directory `/usr/src/kernel/system`?

Comment: rather then edit your Q 12 hrs ago AND add a comment 12 hrs ago, please edit your question with extra **Edit 1 ... n** sections to show your continuing research. You might add a section to your question to show all the steps that you do for an edit /rebuild cycle, as in the document you have included. Better to edit your question to indicate which method you have used from the iinked document. Else people have to guess. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the **main.c** file in /usr/src/kernel folder by adding an additional printf statement in announce method and the following commands worked for me in **MINIX 3.2 version**.

1. Run command "**make install**" inside **/usr/src/kernel** folder.
2. Go to the directory **/usr/src/tools** and run command "**make hdboot**".
3. Restart OS.

Select first option in boot screen and my changes was available.